pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for multiplySchema for langchain AgentExecutor with Gemini-pro
Facing an issue with using AgentExecutor while using the ChatGoogleGenerativeAI.
Integration of the AI agent with tools works fine. But when I use the AgentExecutor, it thorws this error message. I there a prompt for Gemini on the hub? Sometimes the LLM goes into a loop because it can't get the "Final Answer".
Error Message:
python .\playground\gemini_agentexec.py


> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
{'actions': [AgentAction(tool='multiply', tool_input='12, 6', log='Action: multiply\nAction Input: 12, 6')], 'messages': [AIMessage(content='Action: multiply\nAction Input: 12, 6')]}
Action: multiply
Action Input: 12, 6Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\playground\gemini_agentexec.py", line 23, in <module>
    for c in agent_executor.stream(
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1761, in stream
    for step in iterator:
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent_iterator.py", line 199, in __iter__
    for chunk in self.agent_executor._iter_next_step(
  File "C:\Users\username\InHouse LLM\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1403, in _iter_next_step
    yield self._perform_agent_action(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1425, in _perform_agent_action
    observation = tool.run(
                  ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\tools.py", line 615, in run 
    raise error_to_raise
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\tools.py", line 578, in run 
    tool_args, tool_kwargs = self._to_args_and_kwargs(tool_input)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\tools.py", line 501, in _to_args_and_kwargs
    tool_input = self._parse_input(tool_input)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\tools.py", line 450, in _parse_input
    input_args.validate({key_: tool_input})
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 711, in validate    return cls(**value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\project_dir\toolTest\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 341, in __init__    raise validation_error
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for multiplySchema
first_int
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
second_int
  field required (type=value_error.missing)

My code:
from langchain import hub
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_react_agent
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from langchain_community.tools import tool

load_dotenv()

llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro")

@tool 
def multiply(first_int: int, second_int: int):
    '''Multiply two integers together'''
    return first_int * second_int

tools = [multiply]
prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/react")

agent = create_react_agent(llm, tools, prompt)
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)

for c in agent_executor.stream(
    {
        "input": "How much is 12 times six?",
    }
):
    print(c)

This code is taken from the AgentExecutor example for ArXiv. It works when using the ArXiv tool, but fails for simple custom tool. I hope to find the right way to feed the args to the function.
